# Node Js response time decreases under load test

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, performance, rest

I am writing a proof of concept for our existing application.

Architecture of existing application:
Soap Web service is exposed to other systems.
Technology stack of our existing system :- Java -> C++ -> Stored procedures (Oracle Database).
Most of the business logic is written in Stored procedures.

The ask is to make a proof of concept in node js which will replace the existing Java and C++ layer.
Proposed architecture is Node Js -> Stored procedures (Oracle database).

I have couple of questions:

1. The proof of concept in node js(with express) works fine till 100 concurrent users/second where the response time is under a 1s. As the number of concurrent users increase the response time also increases and goes over 1s (the existing application has a SLA of less than 1 second ). 
   The application is deployed on an EC2 instance (same result with t2.micro and m4.large, and the database is also an RDS instance). I have tried using clusters also, but had no significant gain performance.

   How can i improve this such that till 1000 users/second, the response time stays under 1s.
2. Is there any other language/framework that will be suitable for this scenario?

Comment: The question is: what is taking time? Find out, and tune that.  Perhaps follow a standard 'tune the app, then tune the SQL, then tune the DB' approach.  And tune the network and OS and ...

Comment: Thanks Christopher. 

As the current architecture is already able to achieve the desired response time, the DB is side doesn't seem to have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you achieving the desired response time with the current architecture? If yes, then, in theory, the database wouldn't be the issue in the new architecture.

Can you tell us more about the Node.js server setup? Are you using connection pooling? If so, how many connections?  What have you set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE to?

Have you considered standing a load balancer in front of several Node.js instances to spread the load?

Comment: Thanks Dan.  

 I am able to achieve the desired response time with the current architecture. So i also think that the database is not an issue.  

Yes i am using connection pooling with pool size of 30(10-30 pool size gives same results).

As i am new to node dont know much about UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE, will look into it.

Regarding LB, the ask is to get the result without LB initially to see if node is able to handle that.

Is it a realistic target which i am trying to achieve or node just by itself isn't capable of it without doing changes to architecture like introducing LB  etc?

Comment: Node.js uses a thread pool for some async IO operations. node-oracledb uses this thread pool a lot. UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE is an environment variable used to set the number of threads in the pool. The default is 4, because most CPUs these days have 4 cores. However, if you leave the default then, at most, 4 connections can be working at the same time. Try setting it to 30, the number of connections you have in the pool and see how that does. Remember, more isn't always better so experiment with different settings.

Comment: You might care to read the manual https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v1.13.1/doc/api.md#numberofthreads which discusses UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE  Also check it for other tuning tips.